# Invalid use of null error when the code shouldn't be executed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have problem with

> Invalid use of null

error. I know how to avoid it with `Nz`, but it doesn't answer my problem.

I have a function, which builds sql query basing on data from recordset. Here's a  (pseudo)code:

```
string = IIf(Nz(rst.Fields(0).Value, "") = "", "NULL", MyFunction(rst.Fields(0).Value))
```

The code produces `NULL` value, so **I think** it doesn't need to execute `MyFunction` function, but during the runtime I receive above error and it's caused inside `MyFunction` - why?

Comment: Not really enough information here: What is the value of `rst.Fields(0).Value` when you get the error? And what exactly is `MyFunction` defined as?

Comment: Did you define your variable as String? If so, you can't put a NULL value in a String.Define your variable as Variant instead.

Answer (score 1):

As is clearly stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function), VBA's `IIf` function will always evaluate both the *truepart* and the *falsepart*.

If you want to to avoid executing the *falsepart* you will need an actual If-Then-Else block or a Select-Case statement in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify to:

```
Dim NullValue As Variant

NullValue = <some value that will not cause MyFunction to fail>
string = IIf(IsNull(rst.Fields(0).Value), "NULL", MyFunction(Nz(rst.Fields(0).Value, NullValue))
```